# Why $\frac{e^x}{e^x+e^{-y}}$ can't be a joint CDF?

Tags: joint-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

I was trying to come up with an example of a joint CDF, and this function looked to me like a proper one:

$$\frac{e^x}{e^x+e^{-y}} = \frac{e^{x+y}}{e^{x+y}+1}$$

It goes to 1 if you take x and y to infinity, and goes to zero if you take them to minus infinity.

But then I [differentiated it twice](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2nd%20%20derivative%20of%20%28e%5Ex%29%2F%28e%5Ex%2Be%5E-y%29) to get the PDF and saw that it is negative for large part of the domain, which is not allowed.

Here's a profile view from the $X=Y$ position:
[image]

Which made me wonder - what is wrong with this function? i.e. what are the basic rules of probability that break here?

Comment: (Note that the 2nd derivative = 2 partial derivatives w.r.t y and x)

Comment: For instance $F(x,\infty)=F(\infty,y)=1$ is not a cdf. Checking that $F(x,y) grows between $0$ and $1$ when $x$ or $y$ increases is not enough.

Comment: I think you kind of answered your own question --- the problem is that the pdf goes negative.

Comment: @Ben distributions are defined by CDF's, not PDF's. Not all distributions have PDF, and so it doesn't mean a lot if some technicality about the PDF doesn't hold.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't mean a lot?  In your question you say that this outcome (where the PDF goes negative) is "not allowed".

Comment: If the random variable is continuous and has a PDF, then normally this is not allowed (except for countable number of values). But I'm wondering maybe this definition does not cover all cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All bivariate joint CDFs must satisfy what I will call the *rectangle property* which says that if $a < b$ and $c < d$, then the probability that $(X,Y)$ takes on values in the rectangle with sides parallel to the axes and opposite vertices $(a,c)$ and $(b,d)$  is *nonnegative* (as indeed, all probabilities must be). In terms of the joint CDF $F(x,y)$, we have that for *all* choices of real numbers $a,b,c,d$ such that $a < b$ and $c < d$,
$$P(a < X \leq b, c < Y \leq d) = F(b,d) - F(a,d) - F(b,c) + F(a,c) \geq 0.$$
You might want to check if your proposed joint CDF satisfies this property, say for $(a,c) = (0,0)$ and $(b,d) = (\ln 2, \ln 2)$ which makes for easy integer calculations and quick checking.